# How to change colour of inner box in seaborn violinplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am looking to change the colour of the **inner box** plot generated by `sns.violinplot()` to black, see picture below. I've tried using patch but can only find how to do the outer edge of the violin plot and not the inner box. [image: porosity violin plot]

Relevant code:

```
def poros_voilin(data):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.set_style(rc={'patch'})
    ax.axhline(0.84, xmin=0.26, xmax=0.94, color='k')
    ax.annotate(xy=(0.795, 0.63), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(0.795, 0.63), textcoords='axes fraction',
                s='SGL 25 BA')
    ax.axhline(0.78, xmin=0.36, xmax=0.985, color='k')
    ax.annotate(xy=(0.69, 0.535), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(0.69, 0.535), textcoords='axes fraction',
                s='Toaray 060, 090, 120')
    ax.axhline(0.63, xmin=0.485, xmax=0.755, color='k')
    ax.annotate(xy=(0.54, 0.29), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(0.54, 0.29), textcoords='axes fraction',
                s='ELAT LT 1400W')
    vplot = sns.violinplot(y=data['poros'].astype(float), ax=ax)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = load_data() 
    poros_violin(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch artist can be used to change the colour of elements inside of a plot.

```
def poros_voilin(data):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # ax.axhline(0.84, xmin=0.26, xmax=0.98, color='k')
    ax.axhline(0.84, color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
    ax.annotate(xy=(0.98, 0.63), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(0.98, 0.63), textcoords='axes fraction',
                s='SGL 25 BA', ha='right')
    # ax.axhline(0.78, xmin=0.36, xmax=0.98, color='k')
    ax.axhline(0.78, color='k', linestyle='-.', linewidth=1)
    ax.annotate(xy=(0.98, 0.535), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(0.98, 0.535), textcoords='axes fraction',
                s='Toray 060, 090, 120', ha='right')
    # ax.axhline(0.63, xmin=0.485, xmax=0.98, color='k')
    ax.axhline(0.63, color='k', linestyle=':', linewidth=1.5)
    ax.annotate(xy=(0.98, 0.29), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(0.98, 0.29), textcoords='axes fraction',
                s='ELAT LT 1400W', ha='right')
    vplot = sns.violinplot(y=data['poros'].astype(float), ax=ax)
    ax.get_children()[5].set_color('k')  # <------------- changes the colour of the sticks
    ax.get_children()[6].set_color('k')  # <------------- changes the colour of the box
    # sns.boxenplot(y=data['poros'].astype(float), ax=ax)

    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = load_data() 
    poros_violin(data)
```

yields

[image: black box inside vplot]

Comment: this does not change the inner box plot for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the color of the violin plot in the following ways.

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

sns.violinplot( x=df["species"], y=df["sepal_length"], color="skyblue")
```

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

sns.violinplot(x=df["species"], y=df["sepal_length"], color="skyblue", inner=None)
sns.boxenplot(x=df["species"], y=df["sepal_length"], color="red", width=0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to change the color of the violin but i want to change the color of the inner box, from grey to black

Comment: There is also a technique that combines a violin plot with a box plot, which may not be a satisfactory answer for you.

Comment: I ended up using patch artist after all, just couldn't find the object initially when using ax.get_children()